# Automatically select a div onclick

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to create code within an HTML element to automatically select a div? Given `<div onclick="SOME CODE HERE">...</div>`, if a user sees the text and clicks on it the text of the div gets selected.

It works when I create a separate script element that contains the onclick listener, but I’d like to avoid using that since I’d have to add an class to the div

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="selectableDiv">Click me</div>
  <div class="selectableDiv">Click me</div>
  <script>
    const divs = document.getElementsByClassName("selectableDiv");

    for (let div of divs) {
      console.log(div)
      div.onclick = (e) => {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNode(div);
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
        window.getSelection().addRange(range);
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: But... you already have a class on the DIV `class="selectableDiv"`

Comment: *" I’d have to add an class to the div"* - you don't have to add a *class*, you can always add a `data-*` attribute instead - which is also more appropriate when in need to reference elements in JS

Comment: HTML inline JS handlers are a bad coding practice. So before giving any suggestion, and since your question is still an [XY-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), could you first explain why? Why you cannot add attributes to elements (like `class`) but you can bloat `onclick` handlers? What is that you're building actually? Any specific reason for not trying to access elements from a parent Element instead?

Answer (score 0):

I think you’re looking for an [anonymous function](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-anonymous-functions/). Just to note, putting your whole code for the event handler in the onclick event may be considered a bad practice, but if you want to do it, you can add the following inside the onclick of your div element:

```js
(function(){
        const range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNode(event.srcElement);
            window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
            window.getSelection().addRange(range)
    })()
```

So you code would look like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div onclick="(function(){
        const range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNode(event.srcElement);
            window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
            window.getSelection().addRange(range)
    })()">Click me</div>
    <div onclick="(function(){
        const range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNode(event.srcElement);
            window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
            window.getSelection().addRange(range)
    })()">Click me</div>
</body>

</html>
```

A better way of doing this would be:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div onclick="selectText(event)">Click me</div>
    <div onclick="selectText(event)">Click me</div>

    <script>
        function selectText(e) {
            const range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNode(e.srcElement);
            window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
            window.getSelection().addRange(range)
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a function taking an element as a parameter, and then call it from within the div's onclick, passing `this` (the element).

```
<script>
function selectContent(elm) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(elm);
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
}
</script>

<div onclick="selectContent(this)">Click me to select me</div>
```

To avoid any `script` tag altogether, you can do as suggested by @Marco (but passing the element):

```html
<div onclick="(function(elm){
        const range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNode(elm);
            window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
            window.getSelection().addRange(range)
    })(this)">Click me</div>
```

As suggested by @Roko, this is not very clean, and you'd be better off with keeping a way to select the div and use `elm.addEventListener('click', function...` pattern.

Comment: First of, one should avoid the use on HTML inline `on*` handlers.

Comment: @Roko this is literally the OP question `Is there any way to create code within an HTML element`

Comment: Read the reason supporting the [claim idea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: ~Fair enough, I will add an alternative solution~ Edit: actually, how do you identify the divs to add the listeners, if, per the OP:`but I’d like to avoid [...] have to add an class to the div`

Comment: OK, But the question still remains: why the need to avoid using `<script>` but instead go for inline HTML scripting? Why OP can eventually edit *unsafe linline* `on*` handlers but is unable to i.e: add a class, or reference that `div`s from a parent selector? Is OP creating elements dynamically that cannot have a class (for some reason)? Any answer trying to provide a succinct answer to a currently *XY-Problem*, without requiring in comments for further explanation might fail in the long run.

Comment: idk I just answer the question, not trying to judge here, maybe Kassandra has strict requirements and this is a necessary workaround. I still added a disclaimer in my answer to highlight the suboptimal pattern.

Comment: Basically the proper answer would be to use Event delegation from a parent Element targeting *any* DIV child (presuming that those are the only children to be targeted) - but cannot be answered without asking OP directly for clarification.

Comment: Too many assumptions... The question is not "what is the best way to do X"  or "please suggest how to improve ABC", it's pretty clear "I don't want to have a script tag, how can I invoke code from within my HTML element". Anyway, opinions. Have a great day!

Comment: Yes, assumptions exactly! But hopefully OP can reason about them constructively, either confirming your samples and suggestions as a *good-to-go*, or realize there are other means that were not initially considered. Both your answer and the comments are helpful anyways. Happy coding!